# how to show all bubbles with same x,y and z values in fusionchart bubble chart

Tags: fusioncharts, bubble-chart

In bubble chart of fusionchart have no option to show all bubbles under one perticular bubble displaying on chart that have same score and size. But i need to show all bubbles that have same score and size.The other bubbles are hiding under the first bubble.

http://jsfiddle.net/58sYu/1276

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var conversionChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'bubble',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '600',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Sales Analysis of Shoe Brands",
                "subcaption": "Last Quarter",
                "xAxisMinValue": "0",
                "xAxisMaxValue": "100",
                "yAxisMinValue": "0",
                "yAxisMaxValue": "30000",
                "plotFillAlpha": "70",
                "plotFillHoverColor": "#6baa01",
                "showPlotBorder": "0",
                "xAxisName": "Average Price",
                "yAxisName": "Units Sold",
                "numDivlines": "2",
                "showValues":"1",
                "showTrendlineLabels": "0",
                "plotTooltext": "$name : Profit Contribution - $zvalue%",
                "drawQuadrant" : "1",
                "quadrantLineAlpha" : "80",
                "quadrantLineThickness" : "3",
                "quadrantXVal" : "50",
                "quadrantYVal": "15000",
                //Quadrant Labels
                "quadrantLabelTL": "Low Price / High Sale",
                "quadrantLabelTR": "High Price / High Sale",
                "quadrantLabelBL": "Low Price / Low Sale",
                "quadrantLabelBR": "High Price / Low Sale",

                //Cosmetics
                "baseFontColor" : "#333333",
                "baseFont" : "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
                "captionFontSize" : "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize" : "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold" : "0",
                "showBorder" : "0",
                "bgColor" : "#ffffff",
                "showShadow" : "0",
                "canvasBgColor" : "#ffffff",
                "canvasBorderAlpha" : "0",
                "divlineAlpha" : "100",
                "divlineColor" : "#999999",
                "divlineThickness" : "1",
                "divLineIsDashed" : "1",
                "divLineDashLen" : "1",
                "divLineGapLen" : "1",
                "use3dlighting" : "0",
                "showplotborder" : "0",
                "showYAxisLine" : "1",
                "yAxisLineThickness" : "1",
                "yAxisLineColor" : "#999999",
                "showXAxisLine" : "1",
                "xAxisLineThickness" : "1",
                "xAxisLineColor" : "#999999",
                "showAlternateHGridColor" : "0",
                "showAlternateVGridColor" : "0"

            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "label": "$0",
                            "x": "0"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "$20",
                            "x": "20",
                            "showverticalline": "1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "$40",
                            "x": "40",
                            "showverticalline": "1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "$60",
                            "x": "60",
                            "showverticalline": "1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "$80",
                            "x": "80",
                            "showverticalline": "1"
                        }, {
                            "label": "$100",
                            "x": "100",
                            "showverticalline": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "color":"#00aee4",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "x": "80",
                            "y": "15000",
                            "z": "24",
                            "name": "Nike"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "x": "80",
                            "y": "15000",
                            "z": "24",
                            "name": "Adidas"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "x": "80",
                            "y": "15000",
                            "z": "24",
                            "name": "Puma"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "x": "65",
                            "y": "10500",
                            "z": "8",
                            "name": "Fila"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "x": "43",
                            "y": "8750",
                            "z": "5",
                            "name": "Lotto"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "x": "32",
                            "y": "22000",
                            "z": "10",
                            "name": "Reebok"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "x": "44",
                            "y": "13000",
                            "z": "9",
                            "name": "Woodland"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "trendlines": [
                {
                    "line": [
                        {
                            "startValue": "20000",
                            "endValue": "30000",
                            "isTrendZone": "1",
                            "color": "#aaaaaa",
                            "alpha": "14"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "startValue": "10000",
                            "endValue": "20000",
                            "isTrendZone": "1",
                            "color": "#aaaaaa",
                            "alpha": "7"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "vTrendlines": [
                {
                    "line": [
                        {
                            "startValue": "44",
                            "isTrendZone": "0",
                            "color": "#0066cc",
                            "thickness" : "1",
                            "dashed" : "1",
                            "displayValue": "Gross Avg."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    conversionChart.render();
});
```

This the test data edited in fiddle..under first three datas have same size and values so you can see how bubbles are displaying..

Please help

Comment: hey thats probably a concern difficult to get solved by putting all 3 circles in a single circle, because that would be a wrong visual for the smaller circles center.All of these circles ideally should be at a common center right?
Couple of things to solve this - 
1.  in ur data only mention (1+2+3) data. Add a drilldown interaction for that data, so when user clicks on this circle, it drills to another chart.

2. Play with data opacity. Opacity always gives the overlapping looks.

3. Using custom tooltip, u can show a concurrent tooltip.

Any of the above is a correct visualisation.

Comment: There is no solution in fusion chart.. I contact with them :(. I did another method .if more bubble comes and when clicked on that bubble will show a popup and then show all hided bubble there in popup